# Loops with mixing propagator

Tags: tikz-pgf

What is the simplest way to draw such loops?

[image: 1]

I have to place the vertices manually so actually the question is: How to manipulate them that 1 and 2 will be the same size as 3?

Using the [`tikz-feynman`](https://ctan.org/pkg/tikz-feynman) package I was able to achieve the following.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-feynman}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{feynman}
    \vertex (a);
    \vertex [right=of a] (b);
    \diagram* {
      (a) -- (b),
      (a) -- [half left] (b) -- [half left] (a)
    };
  \end{feynman}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: (1) welcome, (2) what code do you already have? (people here generally do not like questions with the undertone "please do this for me", at least show what you have code wise so far)

Comment: OMG, I have  `\begin{tikzpicture}
 \begin{feynman}
 \end{feynman}
\end{tikzpicture}`  What does it change? I know how to draw the third one but I don't know how to manipulate vertices in 1 and 2 that they still will be the same size as 3.

Comment: Please show us a compilable example of your code that shows the third picture.

Comment: `\begin{tikzpicture}  
 \begin{feynman}  
  \vertex (a);  
  \vertex [right=of a] (b);  
  \diagram* { (a) -- (b),  
  (a) -- [half left] (b) -- [half left] (a) };  
 \end{feynman}  
\end{tikzpicture}`  I'm not expecting to get finished task but some example of command which I can use.

Comment: Your code is a fragment, but not compilable.

Comment: Also, please edit your question using the `edit` link and add your (compilable) code there.

Answer (score 1):

Like this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-feynman}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \def\vertices{
    \vertex (a)  at (0, 0);
    \vertex (up) at (1, 1);
    \vertex (md) at (1, 0);
    \vertex (dn) at (1,-1);
    \vertex (b)  at (2, 0);
  }

  \begin{feynman}
    \vertices
    \diagram* {
      (a) -- (md) -- (b),
      (a) -- [quarter left ] (up) -- [quarter left ,photon] (b),
      (a) -- [quarter right] (dn) -- [quarter right,photon] (b)
    };
  \end{feynman}

  \begin{feynman}[xshift=3cm]
    \vertices
    \diagram* {
      (a) -- (md) -- [photon] (b),
      (a) -- [quarter left ] (up) -- [quarter left ] (b),
      (a) -- [quarter right] (dn) -- [quarter right] (b)
    };
  \end{feynman}

  \begin{feynman}[xshift=6cm]
    \vertices
    \diagram* {
      (a) -- (md) -- (b),
      (a) -- [quarter left ] (up) -- [quarter left ] (b),
      (a) -- [quarter right] (dn) -- [quarter right] (b)
    };
  \end{feynman}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]